# Pagination in MVC music store storecontroller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination

I have a large number of products and if I really don't apply paging, the browse page will be way to crowded with data.

So I'm looking for a way to apply paging at the browse action in the storecontroller.

I tried something like this but it won't even work

```
public ActionResult Browse(string genre, int? page) {
    const int pageSize = 10;
    // Retrieve Genre and its Associated Albums from database
    var genreModel = storeDB.Genres.Include("Albums").Single(g => g.Name == genre);

    var paginatedoutput = genreModel.Skip((page ?? 0) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();

    return View(paginatedoutput);
}
```

Comment: The code looks ok. What is the issue? Note that passing page=1 will actually give you page 2.

Comment: 'MvcMusicStore.Models.Genre' does not contain a defintion for 'Skip' and no extension method 'Skip' accepting a first argument of type 'MvcMusicStore.Models.Genre' could be found(are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?
The above error is what im getting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't page it in the controller. I'd do it client side with something like [JQuery Databases](http://datatables.net). That way your app is more responsive. You useful features like searching and sorting built in. Just need to apply it to a standard table. Generally your code will work out far simpler as your controllers don't become cluttered with paging logic etc.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.standard-grid').dataTable();
} );
```

Give any table you want the class standard grid and it will now be a styled data table. You can also enable searching and sorting on it.

If you huge amount of data you can populate via Ajax requests

Comment: well,what i intend doing is to show products images and their title in which user can select;not a grid/table like structure.....
As for d down vote,i really dont know hw dt happened.....

Comment: I would still look at doing it client side. E.g. Using some sort of JQuery plugin etc http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-pagination-plugins/#.UHKHB03A-5I.

Comment: ended up with a client side solution "jPages";works fine and honestly,im done with it...But will still like to  know how it would av been done at the server side(Controller)

Comment: Glad you got it working client side. Unless you are returning huge amounts of data it will give the clients a more responsive experience. Have a look here if you want to read on the hassle involved with server side http://pagingsortingmvc.codeplex.com/ there are also various other Nuget packages that will help you implement pagination.